# How to fixed heading into two lines despite content being only one line

Tags: html, css

How can I fixed my link heading into two lines despite the text being only one line?

[CodePen Link to Problem](http://codepen.io/cusx/full/wamJJP/)

When the heading is only one line, the position of the ***Comment and Like*** button becomes inconsistent, as shown [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkkTH.jpg) .

I tried using floats to no avail. Then I tried setting the position of the *div.info* relative and having my comment and like button to absolute so that I can take them out of the document flow, but somehow, the comment and like button is still following the document flow.

```
.info
    height: 20em
    position: relative

.comment
    position: absolute
    margin-top: -1.5em
    font-size: 1.2em
    float: left
    padding-left: 3em
    a
        text-decoration: none
        color: white
        &:visited
            color: white
            font-weight: 700
.like
    margin-top: -1.5em
    font-size: 1.2em
    position: absolute
    top: 0
    bottom: 20px
    right: 20px
    // float: right
    padding-right: 3em
```

Comment: It never lets me scroll to see the 5th item. Just saying

Comment: Just pre-set the height   `.article h1{ height: 110px;}`

Comment: Instead of absolute positioning, why not vertical align inline-blocks with the width being set on the comment and like elements since their size never changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too consider your buttons as the footer of each part.
Put the two buttons (comment and like) in the same div, and add it :

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

to the div's class.

My screen seems to be larger than yours : every title is in one line, so buttons are always up.
More, be carefull : when i scroll down the page slide too speed, so I can't read your last item.

Comment: It seems like there is problem with displaying the 5th item, if you don't mind, can you take a picture so I can have a look? Because the 5th item shows nicely on my computer. And by the way, the scroll should happen page by page as I am using Fullpage.js

Comment: Sorry i'm late to answer you. I checked again your site and seems nice now. Good job :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this (remove all the other styles for these elements):

```
.like {
    padding-right: 3em;
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.comment {
    padding-left: 3em;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.info:after, .comment:after, .like:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

That last part is to fix divs height, notice how their height is smaller than inside content due to floating. Sometimes you force the height, but it's usually not good - for instance .info div has 20em height, but see in browser inspector when the browser thinks it is.

Also, if you would like to have more margin at the bottom just add:

```
.info {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Also you could remove unnecessary empty <p></p> between <h1> and info div

Comment: Good solution as well. Pseduo elements is a big sticking point for me. Thanks ! will study it more, seems useful.